# Emails are added in queue but its not been send in otrs

Tags: amazon-ses, otrs

I am using `AWS SES` to send emails from OTRS and emails are not working. Below is the error:

> Mar 18 06:22:47 ip-10-210-28-141 OTRS-otrs.Console.pl-Maint::Email::MailQueue-09[30010]: [Error][Kernel::System::CommunicationLog::_LogError][Line:538]: CommunicationLog(ID:795,AccountType:-,AccountID:-,Direction:Outgoing,Transport:Email,ObjectLogType:Message,ObjectLogID:2233)::Kernel::System::MailQueue => Message could not be sent! Error message: Can't connect to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: !

I am able to telnet to `email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` 
I am able to send emails using SES from the same server via command line but OTRS is not sending email.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug OTRS. In your case OTRS was not possible to create an mail object. The cause can have several issue.

Maybe you are using the wrong SMTP backend module, there are 3 different options, SMTP/SMTPS and SMTPTLS (see also https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/tree/master/Kernel/System/Email)

To get more verbose feedback from the CPAN SMTP module, set `$Self->{Debug} = 3;` at this place https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/blob/master/Kernel/System/Email/SMTP.pm#L32 and check STDOUT what the problem is.